# How to load and update tier price for large products collection for more then 50000 products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, price, products, tierprice

We have more then 50000 products in our website and i want update tier price for existing website.
I have added code for update tier price for 4 customer groups. and it is working for 500 to 600 products. but when i want all products tier price then it is showing 500 error. please give me solution or  how to use callback function in magento2 so that i can update products tier price
I have used code like and it is working 500 to 600 products limit

````
 use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface;
 include('app/bootstrap.php');
 $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
 $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
 $productcollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('entity_id','ASC')->setPageSize(800)->load();;
 $i=1;  
 $tierPrice= array();             
 foreach ($productcollection as $product) 
 { 
         $p_id = $product->getId();
         $p_price = $product->getPrice();
         if($p_price >0)
         { 
             $newPrice1=($p_price /2.5)*2;
             $newPrice2=($p_price /2.5)*1.8; 
             $newPrice3=($p_price /2.5)*1.6;
             $newPrice4=($p_price /2.5)*1.4;
             $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
             $productObj = $productRepository->getById($product->getId());
             $tierPrice[0] = array('website_id' => 0,'cust_group' => 5, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => $newPrice1);
             $tierPrice[1] = array('website_id' => 0,'cust_group' => 6, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => $newPrice2);
             $tierPrice[2] = array('website_id' => 0,'cust_group' => 7, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => $newPrice3);
             $tierPrice[3] = array('website_id' => 0,'cust_group' => 8, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => $newPrice4);
             // $productObj->setPrice(103.59);
             $productObj->setTierPrice($tierPrice);
             $productObj->save();   
             echo "Price Updated for Product Id : " .  $p_id."</br>";
             echo"Product count number " . $i."<br/>";
         }
   $i++;
          
 } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

We have a site with 300k products, and I tried quite a few extensions for loading our data. The best one I've found is from Wyomind - Mass Product Import and Export ($210).

https://www.wyomind.com/mass-product-update-import-magento.html

It handles every loading scenario I've needed, and I just checked - it does tiered pricing too. One feature it has is to upload a large file with all of your data, but only import specified rows. I was able to use this to load 20k rows at a time so that I didn't run out of memory (2GB limit from our host).

My apologies if you are not looking for a paid extension. For us the flexibility and ease of use was well worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
sorry i am not looking paid extension.
i want update tier price using price based on customer group and set different2 price for customer group and using root file like
https://mywebsite.com/update_price.php
and  this file run every day one time.